# Testing a React component with Jest / Enzyme & Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component that uses Axios to fetch data:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        axios("http://localhost/data.json").then(response => {
            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <ul>{this.data.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}</ul>;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write some basic tests around this component. First I just wanted the component to render...

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import Example from "./example";

it.only("Renders", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Example />);
    const li = wrapper.find("li");
    expect(li.length).toBe(2); // there are two items in the data file
});
```

...but the first thing I get is a network error from axios.

I'm new to testing and I know for the testing of components I need to get into mocking etc, but I was under the impression that you could still use live endpoints although it's not optimal.

Is there a way to tell Jest to wait until the component has rendered before making the assertions?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Finally found the reason that that I was getting a network error from Axios - needed this setting in create-react-app test script to set the environment to node...

`"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --testEnvironment=node"`

[This is mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44366115/3402376)

Answer (score 2):

I used spies ([sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.0/spies/)) to test code with asynchronous calls.  The idea with spies is to "spy" on a particular function (i.e. your call back), and assert on whether or not is was called and/or how many times it was called, etc.

> A test spy is a function that records arguments, return value, the value of this and exception thrown (if any) for all its calls.

```
let wrapper = shallow(<ReactComponent/>);
let handleEventSpy = sinon.spy(ReactComponentFile, 'functionName');

it('Event Handled', () => {
  const event = {... event stuffs ...};
  expect(handleEventSpy.called).tobe(false);
  wrapper.simulate('Event', event);
  expect(handleEventSpy.called).tobe(true)
}
```

You can also test asynchronous functions with [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code), where the idea is to wrap the code called an async function passing it a special function that the test can call after the async function has completed.  Mocha also works well with promises and has an even clear syntax.

I'd recommend:

1. Factor your response handler into it's own function

   - Allows testing in isolation from axios using specific test data
   - Depending on how often data updates, there's a performance increase not binding a new function on every call
2. Factor your list renderer into it's own function

   - Same as above
   - Combined with lifecycle hooks, avoids calling the `map` function on a `null` object
3. Utilize [React's component lifecycle hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

   - Fetching data in the `componentDidMount` function is standard
   - Examples/Explanations

     - [Fetching Data](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/)
     - [Axios Example](https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/)
4. Although not a requirement, it's good practice to pass `props` in the constructor to the parent class
5. As suggested, mock axios for testing to avoid making long running asynchronous tasks and use test data objects instead.

   - `jest.mock('axios');`

---

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios("http://localhost/data.json")
      .then(response => this.responseHandler)
      .catch(err => this.errorHandler);
  }

  responseHandler = ({data}) => this.setState({data});
  errorHandler = (err) => { ... handle error ...};
  renderRows = ({data}) = <>{data.map(item => this.renderRow}</>; // React Fragment, fyi
  renderRow = (item) => <li>{item}</li>;

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.renderRows(this.state)}</ul>;
  }
}
```

By breaking components down further it allows you to write much simpler tests, and by breaking your handler apart from the axios call you can use test data instead.  You're not trying to test your API, right?

Comment: Many thanks for that, sounds like that would be good for checking that the call is made as a separate test but as I understand I don’t think it will help with mounting the component and running tests against the output. Ideally I’d like to make an assertion like the rough example I’ve put in the question but it’s not mounting with the data!

Comment: Did you read the docs to Mocha at all?  I linked you to the testing asynchronous code section.  But more than that I think you should break code down more to make testing a whole lot easier.  Generally if you're trying to render your component in a test, you'll need to mock your async api calls.  Jest can do the mocking, and mocha can handle testing asynchronous code, but it's really hard to do both at the same time.  What is it you're even trying to test in your original post?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the second half of your answer on the mobile app before responding - responding too quickly to try not to be rude!  The refactoring you've suggested now makes a lot of sense to me. Testing is new to me and yes - writing parts that are easy to test in isolation makes a lot of sense. You're correct in saying that I'm not looking to test the API - I suppose it's more of an integration test in rendering the whole component with "live" data to assert the whole output.

Comment: Great refactoring tips. Writing tests really shines a light on the value of the Single Responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you never want to put an asynchronous call in a constructor in Javascript. It's an antipattern because objects you create are in an indeterminate state when the constructor returns.

In React, initialization code that calls asynchronous functions often goes into the componentDidMount lifecycle method.

If you return a promise from componentDidMount, Enzyme will wait for the promise to resolve during rendering.

Of course, you will want to mock out axios so that there are no network calls during your tests. You can do that by calling `jest.mock('axios')` in the test file.

Comment: These are really helpful tips, thank you.  "If you return a promise from componentDidMount, Enzyme will wait for the promise to resolve during rendering." - for the purpose of this post this is exactly what I was trying to achieve - test the rendering of the component with data (regardless of whether that's a sound approach to testing or not!)

Comment: @stone Thanks, I meant to also comment on React lifecycles, so I added it.