# How to reproduce Jest “Network Error” - floating bug locally

Tags: javascript, jestjs, axios

When I run tests on pipe lines occasionally I am getting "Network Error" for different files (because of `axios` requests). Though some times I don't get errors at all.

But for some reason I can't get that error locally no matter what I do. I use same node version `v12.16.1`. I have tried to reduce testTimeout to 200 (I got bunch of errors but the were different).

1. So the question is why that error is inconsistent?
2. How I can make it consistent and reproduce it locally?

[image]

Comment: What is the `code` property set to for the axios error? That should tell you what the root cause was for the error (connection timeout, connection aborted, address unreachable, etc)

Comment: @Jacob "error Command failed with exit code 1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one test didn't finished request properly, though test itself finished successfully. As the result next test with request failed. And because of default `maxConcurrency: 5` that could be pretty any test.

Though why I was unable to reproduce it locally is still unclear for me.

Comment: So how did you fix the error occurring while running test suite in pipeline ?

Comment: @Dragon I made sure that all requests are finished (or terminated) before the next test is started.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error like that so then I investigated the reason for it. The reason was mentioned by @Arseniy-II.

The test I had was passing without completing it completely. Its reason was that a promise didn't have ***await*** keyword to wait for the outcome of the function. So the test was running without expecting the outcome and some of the other tests failed with ***Network Error***. Of course, the async function has a few APIs that weren't added by me so it means there was a ***Network Error***.

So I recommend if you have an error like that, check out them:

- Make sure to wait to complete an ***async function***
- Make sure all APIs are added as mock APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this exact error stack intermittently in a quasi-random subset of tests after upgrading to Apollo Client 3.0. The technique outlined here helped me pinpoint the root cause as an upstream test that was calling an unmocked axios.get():

https://hceris.com/jest-fail-test-if-unexpected-network-request-happens/